# Запуск java файла по расписанию

Tags: java, планировщик-задач

Есть java файл, который хотелось бы запускать с определенной периодичностью, например раз в час, подскажите как лучше всего это сделать, создать jar и через виндовский Планировщик заданий запускать или есть какой более правильный способ?

Comment: Это хороший способ.

Comment: А где запускать будете? OS-x, GNU/Linux, AIX, OpenBSD, MS Windows 7,8,10